# how to combine many chart in one page on excel?

Tags: excel, ms-word

I have a assignment with statistic. And I have issue on chart. I want to combine many chart to one sheet.  let's say I have a three of chart then I want combine it to one page no need to separate 3 file excel. I want to combine to one file of excel. how can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can place charts on a regular Excel worksheet and arrange several charts so they print on the same page. You can use the page layout view on the View ribbon to help with sizing and positioning the charts on the page.

This screenshot shows the page layout view with three charts.

[image]